# ClassNotFound exception in fragment in android

Tags: java, android

I have a project where I used fragment which is running properly in android sdk 16(ADT 16), but when I run it on my adt20 then its giving me this exception:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

here is my log:

```
07-29 03:09:00.608: W/dalvikvm(467): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/powergroup/splitview/SplitviewActivity; (11)
07-29 03:09:00.608: W/dalvikvm(467): Link of class 'Lcom/powergroup/splitview/SplitviewActivity;' failed
07-29 03:09:00.667: D/AndroidRuntime(467): Shutting down VM
07-29 03:09:00.677: W/dalvikvm(467): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.powergroup.splitview/com.powergroup.splitview.SplitviewActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.powergroup.splitview.SplitviewActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.powergroup.splitview-2.apk]
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.powergroup.splitview.SplitviewActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.powergroup.splitview-2.apk]
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
07-29 03:09:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  ... 11 more
07-29 03:09:03.568: I/Process(467): Sending signal. PID: 467 SIG: 9
```

If its an error then why its running properly in skd 16? I am stuck here totally :(

Comment: From documentation: *ClassNotFoundException*: Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name, *Means*: the version where you are trying to execute it and the exception is thrown doesn't have a specific class, throwing then this exception. Do you have the class name?

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: I am not clear about your reply

Comment: Do you have a class called this: `SplitviewActivity`is it in this package: `com.powergroup.splitview`

Comment: Yess I have and its running in sdk 16

Comment: i am facing the same problem in fragment.plz help.